# spring war file deployed to tomcat 9 but not redirecting properly?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat

Application working and redirecting to views on local machine.

**http://localhost:8080/login**

once project war file orbiter.war deployed on aws server project is running getting login page.

**http://ec2.__compute__amazonaws.com:8080/orbiter/**
[image]

after login it is redirecting to welcome view which is **404 not found**

*http://ec2.__compute__amazonaws.com:8080/welcome*
[image]

but when i go to orbiter/welcome manully its redirecting.

*http://ec2.__compute__amazonaws.com:8080/orbiter/welcome*

[image]

**login controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/login" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showLoginPage() {
    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleUserLogin(ModelMap model, @RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String password) {
    return "redirect:welcome";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showWelcomeDashboard(ModelMap model) {
    LOG.info(" Welcome to Orbiter");
    //LOG.info("User Count"+loginDao.msJdbcTest());
    //model.put("vList",null);
    return "welcome";
}
```

**web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml -->
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Orbiter</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.do</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**dispatcher servlet file spring-servlet.xml**

```
<!-- Configuration defining views files -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="/webjars/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/assets/" cache-period="31556926" />
```

Comment: Try `return "redirect:/welcome";`

Answer (score 0):

clearly your url mapping is incorrect.

this url is not serving the application:

```
http://ec2.__compute__amazonaws.com:8080/welcome
```

But this one is working:

```
http://ec2.__compute__amazonaws.com:8080/orbiter/welcome
```

So correct your mapping and point it to `orbiter/welcome`, 
Maybe you are doing some silly mistake.

Comment: i tried to deploy war file as ROOT.war . Then everything works fine as local machine. is it good approach to deploy in root?

Answer (score 0):

change your mapping to 
http://"your_url".com:8080/orbiter/welcome